# Very slow connection on an Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN

Tags: 11.10, wireless, intel-wireless

So my wi-fi card is a Intel 5100 AGN and so far doesnt works. if anyone managed to make it work give me any hint. Ubuntu user :)
[tried disabling ipv6](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1785-resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal) - no result

Comment: helloooo?! @Jorge Castro, re-edit a bit the title of question :)

Comment: Maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79721/wifi-connection-slow-after-upgrade-to-11-10/108680#108680

Answer (score 11):

There is a problem with kernel 3.0.0.x and Intel wifi under 802.11n.

We are all waiting for the fix in the kernel.

There is a workaround:

1. Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/intel_11n_disable.conf` containing :

   ```
   options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
   ```
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. reboot or `sudo modprobe -r iwlagn && sudo modprobe iwlagn`

Ref:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/871254

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Asus u52f with 02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 (rev 5f)

Comment: It's still not fixed in kernel 3.3-precise. This workaround works like a charm.

Comment: worked for me too.  Lost wireless after upgrade to 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for 12.04 and later, you need to replace all references of iwlagn with iwlwifi (at least, according to what I've read). That's what worked for me with my Intel Pro Wireless 5100 on 13.04.

1. Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/intel_11n_disable.conf` containing:

   ```
   options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
   ```
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. reboot

(other answers say to run modprobe, but it always said my wifi was in use, even when disabled, so reboot was required for me)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since I got downvoted, I changed the answer a bit:

1. Backup the .deb files, just in case:

   ```
   sudo apt-get download network-manager network-manager-gnome
   ```

This will download two .deb package files in your home directory

1. Purge network manager and install wicd

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
   sudo apt-get install wicd wicd-gtk
   ```
2. Reboot. Try to connect using wicd.

If anything goes wrong, just purge wicd and reinstall network manager:

```
sudo apt-get purge wicd wicd-gtk
sudo dpkg -i network-manager*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Did disable via options iwlagn 11n_disable=1

After a kernel update to 3.0.0.13-generic i tried to set

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=0
```

This did enable N speed without the reappearance of the lost and slow connections or dead dd-wrt access points.

Answer (score 0):

This :

> There is a problem with kernel 3.0.0.x and Intel wifi under 802.11n.
> We are all waiting for the fix in the kernel.
> There is a workaround:
>
> 1. Create a file /etc/modprobe.d/intel_11n_disable.conf containing :
>
>    options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
> 2. sudo update-initramfs -u
> 3. reboot or sudo modprobe -r iwlagn && sudo modprobe iwlagn
>
> Ref:
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/871254

works for me, EXCEPT that I need to do it every time I reboot :(

I wrote a script to spare me a bit of pain but I'd be SO grateful if someone could tell me why it's not persistent and mainly how to make it persistent!

Thanks everybody!

P.S. : my wifi controller details:

```
$ lspci -v
...
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at c0300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
...
```