# Slow internet with a Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: 11.10, intel-wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very slow connection on an Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66810/very-slow-connection-on-an-intelr-wifi-link-5100-agn)

Compared my internet speed against a Windows laptop via speed test and noticed a huge difference.

Ubuntu 11.10 (Up: 0.92Mbps Down: 0.92Mbps)

Windows 7 x64 (Up:6.84Mbps Down: 1.07Mbps on Windows)

Info as below:
I have a Dell 1525 Inspiron, Intel wifi card (a/b/g) only. Wireless router only supports b/g. More info below:

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Awesome"
>             Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 00:24:17:80:42:91
>             Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm
>             Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:off
>             Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm
>             Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>             Tx excessive retries:41  Invalid misc:1149811   Missed beacon:0

Clearly the n channel bug would not be the issue here. Also tried the IPv6 disabling solution which also did not work.

Please let me know if any other info might be needed. Have started using Linux only about a week back.

Cheers,

Desu

Comment: atheros?  I had to create `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` and add 
`options ath9k nohwcrypt=1`

Comment: Nope Intel wi fi card. Cheers anyways.

Comment: Okay something has clearly worked since I last checked and the latest speedtest run yielded these results; Down: 5.84 Mbps Up: 0.94 Mbps. My guess would be the IPv6 disabling was the champion trick!

Comment: @Desu if that did the trick don't forget to come back later and post your solution as an answer so we can vote it up!

Comment: Detailed report to follow soon, solution seems temperamental. Apologies for the late reply.

Comment: IPv6 disabling works but as soon as you launch torrent client (transmission, in my case) the speeds dip right back. Now I am trying it with a different torrent client (Vuze) but I suppose the real solution would be disabling "the" feature on the software that's leading to this problem.

Comment: Update: Doesn't seem like its working, I did not even use any torrent client which might just have been an artifact but the problem still lingers. Restarting the computer helps but after 15 mins the problem is back to square zero...honestly I am lost here! As a newbie to Linux my capabilities at this point are limited to googling and mining for more info..

Comment: Does the same thing happen with a hard wired connection? It's likely just a wifi driver issue.