# WiFi connecting and dropping immediately (ubuntu 16.04, tkip network)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

Been dealing with this issue at work, can't connect to the Wifi network here.

It works on another of my laptop with the same OS and a different network card, but this Thinkpad T401s with a rtl8191sevb card can't stay connected.

The wifi will connect, ping or any other network service won't work, and after a few seconds it disconnects me. Then it just loops over that endlessly.

Following is the syslog when this happens.

We can see that I'm getting a DHCP lease, but then we start seeing something like "Michael MIC failure detected", and "TKIP countermeasures started" just before "deauthenticating from 02:18:4a:bb:32:f0 by local choice (Reason: 14=MIC_FAILURE)"

The network here is using WPA2 with TKIP (not AES)

**Things I tried so far:**

Uninstall TLP, disable power saving in the BIOS, disabled wifi card power saving.

sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

sudo killall wpa_supplicant

Adding "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" to iwlwifi.conf

Unfortunately this is not my AP so I have to live with TKIP. Any ideas?

Here is the paste from wireless-info: https://pastebin.com/M4VtvDqM

Here are the system logs when this issue is occurring: https://pastebin.com/zL9NrY0q

Quite frustrating that this works on 3 out of my 4 machines. Just this one thinkpad 410s is giving me troubles!

Thanks!

Comment: `Sep 27 16:06:45 t410s wpa_supplicant[1162]: wlp3s0: Michael MIC failure detected` and `kernel: [  232.254544] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 02:18:4a:bb:32:f0 by local choice (Reason: 14=MIC_FAILURE)` and `Sep 27 16:06:49 t410s NetworkManager[972]: <warn>  [1506553609.5351] sup-iface[0x1c5d7a0,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -14)` deserve investigation. `perror 14` says `OS error code  14:  Bad address`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've done quite a bit of research before posting here, hence why there's quite a lot of things under "things I tried so far". For example I tried everything on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343446/wifi-has-trouble-connecting-constantly-disconnects-in-ubuntu

Comment: Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Anyone wanna take a stab at this? Would love for this computer to work right!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to permanently fix the problem by installing windows 10. Now the wireless works perfectly!!

One day Linux will be ready for the desktop! Slowly getting there